# How to open terminal on run of .sh file in linux?

Tags: linux, terminal, sh

So i have my file run.sh :

```
#!/bin/bash
rails s
cd public/angular
grunt serve
```

Right now if i run sh run.sh i start rails server, but grunt serve is never fired. But the main problem i am strugling with is that i want to open a separate terminal window where rails s fires, and afterwards open second terminal windows where grunt serve is runned.

So it should look something like :

```
     #!/bin/bash
Open new terminal window ->
       run rails s in newly opened window
        cd public/angular
open second terminal window
       run grunt serve in second terminal window
```

Is it possible to do this in .sh file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would something like this work?

```
#!/bin/bash
xterm -e "rails s"
cd public/angular
xterm -e "grunt serve"
```

Replace `xterm` with your preferred terminal emulator (`gnome-terminal`, `konsole`, etc.).

Comment: Perfect! exactly what i wanted! ill accept as soon as i will be allowed